# Unable to serve static assets with an efficient cache policy in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, apache2, laravel-9

I am trying Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy. I am using Laravel 9 on a apache2 server.

Below is the code i have used in the .htaccess file to enable leverage browser caching:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On

 # Images
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

  # Video
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"

  # Fonts
  ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"

  # CSS, JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

  # Others
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Even after adding the above code in .htaccess file, I am still getting the same error/notification in lighthouse and google search insights.

HTTP response headers:

```
cache-control: no-cache, private
cf-cache-status: MISS
cf-ray: 7b4367722899850d-BOM
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Fri, 07 Apr 2023 15:46:35 GMT
last-modified: Fri, 07 Apr 2023 15:46:34 GMT
server: cloudflare
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjZLWldVc1JteUdFTkhZeVJYbU5wemc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVXJMR241MjYrK3pRM0tZeDFDUWpqU0ZVcnVneHZYdUg1REo2U3hqZnhkSmsyK2piRC96dEdzQ1B1WTNKeG5VL2E5Z0Z5eHYycEhRUHFlNzliRithamQvVU9GWmpmSEVOQS9hM1FrTCsyZjVZOGplbTdzQWVzMUg4YkRGNWVzWC8iLCJtYWMiOiI4MjQwY2VjZmFkNjQzOTY1OTZmNzliNjNhZDdiYTRjMTYyNGRlNTdkZDQ0MmY4OGMxOGYwODg4ZDgwNjEzODkxIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Fri, 07-Apr-2023 17:46:34 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
set-cookie: phprank_session=eyJpdiI6Iks2ekpzdFhsRy9FRCs4UFBSdU5OR2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiS2M0WGNwVzE1VS9YTkE4SUxFUVM1SXY1bmNEbWV5d1BJcTBZRVBzU3NlVFkzdEpBOTZTMFhDeXlRcmtxa0s3OWFwZzV2amIvY1NSZ2E0cVRxNkJsNEdPQWxSUTNrWnEvTnBUSitGRGRHTUhIREVIM2wrVmJQSkRieDBlZzdORkwiLCJtYWMiOiI4YjNhODJjZTVlYTJmOGMyMDA5OTcwZDM2NDY5N2I3NmU1MjQ1NjkzMjBlZjI5ODEzZTg2MWZhNzQzOWY5YmIxIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Fri, 07-Apr-2023 17:46:34 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
```

Edit 1 :

I have also added the below code in the .htaccess file:

```
<filesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|svg|ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: What are the HTTP response headers for such a request?

Comment: @MrWhite, i have edited the question and added the HTTP response header to the question.